# how return value form use hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
export function useCulture(): [string, boolean] {

  let result:[string, boolean] = [null, null]
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const { valid, culture } = validateCulture();
    result = [culture, valid];
  }, [Router?.router?.asPath]);

  console.log(result);
  return result;
};
```

always returns [null, null] array;

need return [culture, valid] values

How to fix it,
Maybe need return value from useEffect;

Maybe need return value from useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use state so it updates the value after the component mounts and the function is exicuted.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useCulture(): [string, boolean] | undefined {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<[string, boolean]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { valid, culture } = validateCulture();
    setResult([culture, valid]);
  }, []);//add deps that are used inside the effect or should trigger an update

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an effect here at all? Why do you need state? There's nothing `async` going on.

Comment: The result will always be undefined or if set, the initial value.  The value is set in the effect - but the UI won't reflect the updated value without a re-render.  Using state will tell react to show the updated value as well as persist the value between re-renders.